# Azure file storage unable to load files

Tags: python, azure

Im trying to store a file in windows azure using their python api but get the following error:-

Error:-

```
azure.common.AzureMissingResourceHttpError: The specified parent path does not exist.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>ParentNotFound</Code><Message>The specified parent path does not exist.
RequestId:ef08c863-001a-0174-6240-e12dfd000000
Time:2017-06-09T16:47:49.6213824Z</Message></Error>
```

Here is the python code:-

```
file_service = FileService(account_name='example',                  account_key='fE0mXXgCHRqxrOdxKu9e4BI4o57E6LTUacX40n/KZNw==')
local_file_path = os.path.join(subdir, file) 
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:        
        result = file_service.create_file_from_path(
                    'test',
                    subdir.split(os.path.sep)[-1],
                    'testfile',
                    local_file_path,
                    # content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type='image/png')
                    )
```

Comment: If it is your real key, please remove/anonymize your `account_key` variable in your question. And you should probably update it!

Comment: Unless you have created the directory somewhere else in your script, you cannot upload a file into a directory that does not pre-exist or that you have not created (and therefore does not exist). If you change `subdir.split(os.path.sep)[-1]` to `None` then you will upload into the root directory of your file storage and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

According to your error information and the code, I think your issue is as the same as the other SO thread [How to copy file from one directory to other in azure through java service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44236289/how-to-copy-file-from-one-directory-to-other-in-azure-through-java-service/44238916#44238916). It was caused by create a file in a nonexistent path of a share of Azure File Storage, even the parent directories or paths are not exist.

So you need to check and create these parent directories one by one from your `test` share to the directory kids firstly, using the method [`create_directory(share_name, directory_name, metadata=None, fail_on_exist=False, timeout=None)`](http://azure-storage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/azure.storage.file.fileservice.html#azure.storage.file.fileservice.FileService.create_directory) with the argument `fail_on_exist=True` in Python as below.

```
file_service = FileService(account_name='example', account_key='fE0mXXgCHRqxrOdxKu9e4BI4o57E6LTUacX40n/KZNw==')
local_file_path = os.path.join(subdir, file) 
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    # First to check and create the parent directory whether be exist.
    file_service.create_directory('test', subdir, fail_on_exist=True)
    for file in files:        
        result = file_service.create_file_from_path(
                    'test',
                    subdir.split(os.path.sep)[-1],
                    'testfile',
                    local_file_path,
                    # content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type='image/png')
                    )
```